# Remove field in Customer Account Information

Tags: admin, customer

I am trying to remove the `Associate to Website` field on the following page:

`Customers -> Manage Customers -> Click on a customer -> Account Information`

I have checked `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account::initForm()` in this file:

`app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php`

but I am unsure how it loads the fields and how to remove a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest solution is in the file that you mentioned - **app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php** in **public function initForm()** to comment/remove this lines:

```
$renderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/store_switcher_form_renderer_fieldset_element');
$form->getElement('website_id')->setRenderer($renderer);
```

and below them to add:

```
$fieldset->removeField('website_id');
```

Comment: Upvote for you!!

Comment: HI @michael, How to do that in Magento 2. I am using Magento 2 right now.